# String.IndexOf fails on Xamarin.Android (Mono) but not on .NET Framework

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, mono

The line below returns -1 (incorrect) on Xamarin.Android and 2 (correct) on .NET Framework:

```
"ビューアー".IndexOf("ー")
```

Looking in the Mono source code, SimpleCollator.cs, I can see that character "ー" (0x30FC) has special handling.

Is there a way to make this line work properly in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different from  .NET Framework . In Xamarin (iOS and Android)  , we need to implement **localization** to support multiple languages . In your case ,  the easiest way is to ignore the **Language** and **Area** .

```
var index = "ビューアー".IndexOf("ー",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

For more details about localization you could refer [Xamarin.Android Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/localization) .